# Laravel route "air" gives me permission error on new installed laravel. but other routes are OK

Tags: php, laravel, wamp

I have just installed laravel and `php artisan key:generate` then `compoer install` and after that set database configuration, and didn't touch anything else!

I created a route for test :

```
Route::get('air', 'HomeController@air');
```

It gives me this error :

```
You don't have permission to access /air/ on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.6.18 Server at test.dev Port 80
```

The Controller and view are fine and they are working, when I change the route  :

```
Route::get('aair', 'HomeController@air');
Route::get('aaair', 'HomeController@air');
Route::get('aird', 'HomeController@air');
Route::get('test', 'HomeController@air');
```

All these routes are working with no errors!! It is so weird!

I have laravel 5.4.9 and wampserver3 64bit on win 7